# Laravel's Eloquent pivot object

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

I have defined relation in my model:

```
public function positions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Position', 'users_positions')->withPivot('season');
}
```

Is it possible to display objects with pivot in cleaner way?
For Example:

```
"positions": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "A",
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "position_id": 1,
                    "season": 2014
                }
            }
        ],
```

I would like to get:

```
"positions": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "A",
                "season": 2014
            }
        ],
```

Comment: By display do you mean when you convert it into an array/JSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators):

```
public function getSeasonAttribute()
{
   return ($this->pivot) ? $this->pivot->season : null;
}
```

Then you can access it just like other properties:

```
$position = $someModel->positions->first();
$position->season;
```

if you also need it in the `toArray/toJson` output, then use on you model:

```
protected $appends = ['season'];
```